# Different ad on sidebar when user refreshes page or navigates to different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a sidebar with a section for an ad. I want to display a different ad on that section when the user navigates to a different page or refreshes the page. I want to rotate about 5-10 ads. Each ad is a script therefore having more than 10 ads will slow down my page. What is the best way to rotate ads on refresh or when a user navigates to a different page? It is for my wordpress blog but I prefer not to use plugins.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/solxs9/6Z7ex/)

```
<?php 
  $ads = array("ad code goes here", "more ad code", "more ad code");
  shuffle($ads);
  print $ads;
 ?>
```

I tried this but no luck. I think javascript would be a better fit. Or what would be the best fit with out slowing down my web page.

Comment: Your PHP code is working, if you want to display your ads just use a `foreach` loop instead of directly using a print function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, try this one

```
<?
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
echo $input[$rand_keys];
?>
```

thank you try this